# Add empty JSON Array to JSON String in SQL Server table column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following JSON in my `Data` column of the SQL Server table `Activity`:

```
{ "Id": 6, "Name": "Name 1", "ProjectName": "Project 1" }
{ "Id": 6, "Name": "Name 2", "ProjectName": "Project 2", "Users":[ "user1.name@domain.com", "user2.name@domain.com" ] }
```

I need to write a SQL query to update all the records of `Data` column and set `Users = []` in the `Activity` table.

Example: the 1st sample record mentioned here should look like this:

```
{ "Id": 6, "Name": "Name 1", "ProjectName": "Project 1", "Users": [] }
```

I tried with the following query.

```
UPDATE Activities  
SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(Data, '$.Users', JSON_OBJECT())
WHERE Id = 1
```

I get this error:

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '⸤' is found at position 0.

The other query updates the JSON but adds the value as a string,

```
UPDATE Activities  
SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(Data, '$.Users', '[]')
WHERE Id = 1
```

Output:

```
{ "Id": 6, "Name": "Name 1", "ProjectName": "Project 1", "Users": "[]" }
```

Can you please suggest a suitable SQL script to update the records?

Comment: Have you tried the first query with `JSON_ARRAY()` instead of `JSON_OBJECT()`? [Microsoft - JSON_ARRAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-array-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
UPDATE Activities  
SET Data = JSON_MODIFY(Data, '$.Users', JSON_QUERY('[]'))
WHERE Id = 1
```

As @topsail mentioned in the comment section, here's an explanation of the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/injecting-json-objects-into-existing-json-text-with-json_modify-function

Comment: @topsail thanks for the constructive comment. Your first link was already added to my answer, but I edited it and added your second link.